# what are the differences in NServiceBus.Distributor and Master node

Tags: nservicebus

I am using NService bus 3.0, should I use Master profile or NServiceBus.Distributor for load balancing?

Answer (score 2):

The Master profile essentially combines the duties of the NServiceBus 2.6 Distributor along with being a worker node itself, at least, with respect to load distribution.

A Master node also does other things depending on other configurations, such as acting as the timeout manager, gateway, etc.

The Distributor profile, on the other hand, turns the endpoint into a distributor ONLY. In effect, it becomes like an NServiceBus 2.6 distributor. It distributes messages but does not participate in processing them on its own.

The Distributor is useful for the scenario when you are putting a bunch of distributors on a failover cluster (read: expensive) and you don't want to waste those expensive resources on processing messages, because you have cheaper servers to handle that.

For more information see [More on Profiles](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/nservicebus-host/profiles) in the NServiceBus Documentation, specifically the heading "Feature Related Profiles"

**EDIT**

With regard to not running Worker nodes in a failover cluster, it appears that in V3 things aren't quite set up the way they should be, which is (conceptually) running the Distributor and Timeout Manager in the Master on the cluster (with no worker), and then only running the workers as satellites. See this [thread in the NServiceBus discussion group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/17758) and the [comments on this answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718083/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-the-timeout-manager-with-the-distributor-in-nserv#answer-14723205) for more info.

Comment: I do hope its possible to run the Distributor profile together with the timeout manager, I do NOT want to install worker nodes on the failover cluster.

Comment: Edited my answer with more information, however unfortunately you'll probably find it a bit incomplete for now.

Comment: No problem running the timeout manager on the distributor, but you need to start it yourself. Check out the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718083/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-the-timeout-manager-with-the-distributor-in-nserv